# Django. access database through model on shutdown hook

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Here is my problem, i'm trying to update database through django-model on shutdown signal which is declared on **init**.py file but **database** on model object is **None**

```
import logging
import os
import signal
import sys

from django.db import transaction

logger = logging.getLogger("logger")


def my_signal_handler(*args):
    if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") is not "true":
        return

    from mymodels import MyModel
    logger.info("update models")

    with transaction.atomic():
        for model in MyModel.objects.all():
            if model.my_flag:
                model.my_flag = False
                model.save()
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_signal_handler)
```

Also when i'm trying to import model outside `my_signal_handler` function application throws exception **"django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."**


The question is: what's the better way to append shutdown hook that can access application context

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use django models in standalone mode you should manually call `django.setup()` then you can import and work with your models so change your code to something like this:

```
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()

from mymodels import MyModel
```

so in short first run `django.setup()` then import and work with models

check django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) on this subject